# How to set-up sitemaps on Google App Engine ? (there is no filesystem support)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sitemap

rephrase : Is there any sitemaps generator for GAE / python ? We have dynamic content/pages that expires and gets updated very often but since GAE doesn't allow filesystem access all the existing solutions don't work (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/googlesitemapgenerator/ ) 
 The website will have millions of such dynamic pages.

Comment: What are you using to power your site itself?

Comment: @DanielRoseman python . I think was already specified in the question. Let me know if this answers to your question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to the filesystem, but you can store your content like sitemap.xml in the database (db.Text / db.Blob) or in the blobstore. Below is the code for serving this content.

```
class DynLoad(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, key_name):                                       

        dyn = models.Dynamic.get_by_key_name(key_name)
        if dyn :
            (content_type, _) = mimetypes.guess_type(key_name)
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = content_type
            self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % (key_name)
            self.response.out.write(dyn.content)
```

Comment: I'm aware of the filesystem limitation(I think is obvious from the question too) but I'm wondering if there exists any open source project for this particular job that I can use instead to reinvent the wheel.